# C++ - Store Pointer in byte array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is there any way to store a pointer address inside of a char byte array, byte by byte, and then convert it back to a pointer?

Comment: As shown below that's possible. But don't try to use that to de-/serialize pointers for exchange between processes, or saving and restoring from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Just memcpy it:

```
void* ptr = nullptr;
char buffer[sizeof(void*)];
memcpy(buffer, &ptr, sizeof(void*));
```

And back:

```
memcpy(&ptr, buffer, sizeof(void*));
```

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: It will work on any type of pointer except member-function pointers (which are rather special in C++).  Try it.

Comment: What's the use of doing this

Comment: @AnkitAcharya can't think of any off the top, but sometimes passing an array of char is the only way you can move data across an interface. Just make sure you don't move that pointer into a different memory space and then try to use it.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: For example if you have an interthread communication API which lets you pass arrays of characters around, you might need this.  Because even if you can `send(&ptr, sizeof(ptr))`, on the receiving side you need `memcpy()` to ensure proper alignment of the pointer (if the API does not guarantee alignment and just gives you a `const char*` containing a copy of the "message").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do:

```
void *p = bla;

char temp[sizeof p];
std::memcpy(temp, &p, sizeof p);
// ...
std::memcpy(&p, temp, sizeof p);
```

You may need `#include <cstring>` for `memcpy`.